# WPF dynamic viewbox is not being displayed in my window

Tags: c#, wpf

In my simple WPF app I am creating a viewbox programatically, then I am assigning a textbox object as it's child and finally I am adding this viewbox into my root canvas layout. But when I run my app I'm not seeing it. I debugged my code and I do see the viewbox as part of the children's list in my root layout. Here is my code:

```
public partial class Foo
  {
    Viewbox FooViewBox = null;
    TextBox FooText = null;

    public Foo()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      FooText = new TextBox();
      FooText.Text = "The quick brown fox...";
      FooViewBox = new Viewbox();

      Canvas.SetLeft(FooViewBox, 0); //temp pos x
      Canvas.SetTop(FooViewBox, 0); // temp pos y
      FooViewBox.Width = FooText.Width;
      FooViewBox.Height = FooText.Height;
      FooViewBox.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
      FooViewBox.StretchDirection = StretchDirection.Both;

      FooViewBox.Child = FooText;

      // Add Viewbox to Grid panel's child
      FooLayout.Children.Add(FooViewBox);
    }
```

The strange thing is that I have other UI objects that I load in the same fashion (minus with the view box) and I'm not having this issue. What else do I need to do in order to get it to show? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Setting Width and Height of FooViewBox is pointless, because the TextBox Width and Height is `NaN` unless you also set it explicitly. Besides that, your code works fine for me. However, if FooLayout is actually a Grid, setting Canvas.Left and Top also makes no sense.

Comment: Note also that `Viewbox  FooViewBox = null;` is redundant. In C#, any class members are always initialized to their default value, which is `null` for all reference types. You may however write `private readonly Viewbox fooViewBox = new ViewBox();` and remove the initialization from the constructor. And thus also adhere to a widely accepted naming convention by using a field name that starts with a lowercase letter.

Comment: @Clemens okay I fixed my issue and am now seeing my text on the screen. however... now my text is showing up as "the quick brown...". its cutting out the last part. is there a way to make the text shrink to fit inside the view box?

Comment: That's because you're using a TextBox instead of a TextBlock, and of course it still depends on the actual kind if Panel you're using. Why don't you show your XAML, and why are you doing this in code behind? To me, it doesn't make any sense.